# pandas read_excel multiple tables on the same sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to read multiple tables from a sheet excel file using pandas ?
Something like:
read table1 from row0 until row100
read table2 from row 102 until row202
...

Comment: Why not just read it all in and then separate to different `DataFrame`s in python?

Comment: I don't know exactly how can I achieve that.

Comment: @bsd, do you know the total # of rows beforehand?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming we have the following Excel file:

[image]

**Solution:** we are parsing the first sheet (index: `0`)

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(fn)
nrows = xl.book.sheet_by_index(0).nrows

df1 = xl.parse(0, skipfooter= nrows-(10+1)).dropna(axis=1, how='all')
df2 = xl.parse(0, skiprows=12).dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

EDIT: `skip_footer` was replaced with `skipfooter`

**Result:**

```
In [123]: df1
Out[123]:
    a   b   c
0  78  68  33
1  62  26  30
2  99  35  13
3  73  97   4
4  85   7  53
5  80  20  95
6  40  52  96
7  36  23  76
8  96  73  37
9  39  35  24

In [124]: df2
Out[124]:
   c1  c2  c3 c4
0  78  88  59  a
1  82   4  64  a
2  35   9  78  b
3   0  11  23  b
4  61  53  29  b
5  51  36  72  c
6  59  36  45  c
7   7  64   8  c
8   1  83  46  d
9  30  47  84  d
```

Answer (score 21):

I wrote the following code to identify the multiple tables automatically, in case you have many files you need to process and don't want to look in each one to get the right row numbers. The code also looks for non-empty rows above each table and reads those as table metadata.

```
def parse_excel_sheet(file, sheet_name=0, threshold=5):
    '''parses multiple tables from an excel sheet into multiple data frame objects. Returns [dfs, df_mds], where dfs is a list of data frames and df_mds their potential associated metadata'''
    xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
    entire_sheet = xl.parse(sheet_name=sheet_name)

    # count the number of non-Nan cells in each row and then the change in that number between adjacent rows
    n_values = np.logical_not(entire_sheet.isnull()).sum(axis=1)
    n_values_deltas = n_values[1:] - n_values[:-1].values

    # define the beginnings and ends of tables using delta in n_values
    table_beginnings = n_values_deltas > threshold
    table_beginnings = table_beginnings[table_beginnings].index
    table_endings = n_values_deltas < -threshold
    table_endings = table_endings[table_endings].index
    if len(table_beginnings) < len(table_endings) or len(table_beginnings) > len(table_endings)+1:
        raise BaseException('Could not detect equal number of beginnings and ends')

    # look for metadata before the beginnings of tables
    md_beginnings = []
    for start in table_beginnings:
        md_start = n_values.iloc[:start][n_values==0].index[-1] + 1
        md_beginnings.append(md_start)

    # make data frames
    dfs = []
    df_mds = []
    for ind in range(len(table_beginnings)):
        start = table_beginnings[ind]+1
        if ind < len(table_endings):
            stop = table_endings[ind]
        else:
            stop = entire_sheet.shape[0]
        df = xl.parse(sheet_name=sheet_name, skiprows=start, nrows=stop-start)
        dfs.append(df)

        md = xl.parse(sheet_name=sheet_name, skiprows=md_beginnings[ind], nrows=start-md_beginnings[ind]-1).dropna(axis=1)
        df_mds.append(md)
    return dfs, df_mds
```

Comment: What is `df_mds` list? Because all df placing into `dfs`.

Comment: Nice work @Rotem

Comment: Throws the following exception for me : ValueError: 'nrows' must be an integer >=0

Comment: whats the `threshold` in this function?

Comment: @NoobVB

The threshold variable is a guess on what determines the difference between a table beginning and ending. It's a finicky heuristic in this sense.

the variables n_values and n_values_deltas give some hints as they are a sum of all the elements in a row that ARE NOT NULL, followed by the difference between the previous row and the current row.

It is in essence a form of "edge detection" where you can imagine a step function of index on the x axis and the deltas on the y axis the threshold is a constant line on the positive x and - x axis. When crossed a new table is defined.

Comment: @ZdWhite So if I am looking for a table that has 5 columns, then the first row of this table would trigger an `n_values_deltas` for that row of 5, so I would want "threshold" be no bigger than 4 in this case. Basically, shouldn't the threshold just be one smaller than the number of columns of the smallest table in the sheet? Ahhh, I suppose it get complicated when tables overlap in their rows.

Comment: Wow, now that I have gotten into it more, I really like this function. I have a couple questions though. 1. When I print `n_values` I get a count of 3 in the first position of the output list, when in fact, a count of 3 does not occur in my excel sheet sheet until the second row. Is the function skipping headers or ignoring row 1 for some reason? 2. one of my tables starts in row1 of the excel sheet, however the function seems not re recognize a delta at that index, I suppose because there is no `n_value` that comes before. Is this the case? Thanks for the function!

Answer (score 5):

First read in the entire `csv` file:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('path_to\\your_data.csv')
```

and then obtain the individual frames, for example using:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:100,:]
df2 = df.iloc[100:200,:]
```

Comment: if it would be a CSV file we could simply use `skiprows` and `nrows` parameters. Unfortunately the `nrows` is not implemented for `pd.read_excel`