# Pandas read_excel multiple tables from 1 sheet with multiindex headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I needed to read few tables from manualy made excel. Here I found a solution:

[pandas read_excel multiple tables on the same sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367805/pandas-read-excel-multiple-tables-on-the-same-sheet)

But it didn't fix my whole problem, because some of my tables has multiindex column names. I tried this way:[excel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11upZ.png)

```
nrows = excel_file.book.sheet_by_index(0).nrows  
table2 = excel_file.parse(0, skiprows=6, skip_footer=nrows - 11, header=[0,1,2]).dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

and in this cases I have "ValueError: Length of new names must be 1, got 3"

I have found that if my excel file will look like this:[modified excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Dr4X.png)
(without columns in other tables that are longer than table i read) then it works! How can I solve this problem?