# Export two excel data into single excel sheet by adding heading and some calculated data

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, reactjs, csv

I am using [**react-data-export**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-export) to export the excel sheet in my react project. I need to export two excel data in single file. Example

[image]

If not possible the above module please suggest me a new way to do so.

Comment: sir, I think you should look at this - [pandas read excel multiple tables on the same sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367805/pandas-read-excel-multiple-tables-on-the-same-sheet)

Answer (score 4):

I have published a [simple proof of concept](https://github.com/rondinif/react-data-export-dataset-poc) that it should be useful to understand how it is possible to satisfy the needs in the question to export two excel data in single file.

[image]
In the  **`ExcelSheet`** components it is possible to pass a [`dataSet`](https://github.com/securedeveloper/react-data-export/blob/094f67fa02a491b0f0a248c8f83bc617c8166568/src/ExcelPlugin/utils/DataUtil.js#L26) that allows any number of **data tables** and other features such as column headers and the offset in rows and columns between a **data table** and the subsequent one.

- The `data` attribute of `ExcelSheet` is for one data table.
- The `dataSet` attribute of `ExcelSheet` is for one or more data table

In the **react-data-export** git repo there is also an example [simple_excel_export_02](https://github.com/securedeveloper/react-data-export/blob/master/examples/simple_excel_export_02.md) but I have not been able to make it work, also there is a [open issue](https://github.com/securedeveloper/react-data-export/issues/130) with some suggestions I've learned for my POC.

Comment: This is a hack which can be done but still how can I add the heading and the calculated data?

Comment: @Profer this question ask how to export two excel data in single file:  for fairness you should open another different question well specifying what you can't do as **calculated data** ;    for the additional header is concerned, we can try to add an empty table with only one header column and no data

Comment: @Profer: just added a new branch with the solution for additional heading https://github.com/rondinif/react-data-export-dataset-poc/tree/additional-headings

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. I will try it in future but as of now it does not fulfil my requirements because I have clearly shown in the question about the exported format(we cannot write everything in the question it self). BTW I have used npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs by writing it on back-end and then download it on front-end. I will answer it surely and also will offer you the bounty on the last day if do not get any answer. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

Inside ExcelSheet there is a property called **dataSet**. which is used to generate data to our excel. So you can add multiple data to the dataSet. Please see my code below. Here I am using field called **generatedData**, which contains rows and columns for our excel. So you can add multiple objects of data inside array to order in your single excel sheet. Result will be exactly what you asking above

```
import ReactExport from 'react-data-export';
const ExcelFile = ReactExport.ExcelFile;
const ExcelSheet = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelSheet;
const ExcelColumn = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelColumn;

const VesselReportExcelGenerator = (props) => {
    const [exportModalOpen, setExportModalOpen] = useState(false);
    const [excelData, setExcelData] = useState([]);
    const vesselReportApi = new VesselReportApi();
    var generatedData = [
        {
            columns: columns,
            data: excelData
        },
        {
            columns: columns,
            data: excelData
        }
    ];

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchVesselReportFormStructure();
    }, []);

    const fetchVesselReportFormStructure = async () => {
        try {
            const vesselReportFormStructure = await vesselReportApi.getVesselReportFormStructure();
            setExcelData(vesselReportFormStructure);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            props.setMessages([{type : "danger", message : 'Something went wrong. Please try again!'}]);
        }
    };

    return (
        <Container fluid className="VesselReportExcelBackground">
            <Col lg={7}>
                <Row style={{ justifyContent: 'center', height: '2rem',paddingTop: "40px",height: "10%" }}>
                    <div style={{fontSize: "2rem",color: config.KSTColors.MAIN,fontWeight: "900",}}>
                        OFFLINE VESSEL REPORT
                    </div>
                </Row>
                {/* Export Vessel report excel UI */}
                <Row xs={12} md={3} style={{backgroundColor: config.KSTColors.CARD_BG,height: "150px",borderRadius: "15px",marginTop: "40px"}}>
                    <Col xs={3} lg={3} style={{ padding: "0px" }}>
                        <Button className="VesselReportExcelEditButton" style={{ backgroundColor: config.KSTColors.MAIN,borderColor: config.KSTColors.MAIN,width: "100%"}} onClick={() => setExportModalOpen(true)}>
                            {/* <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFileExport} style={{color: config.KSTColors.ICON,fontSize: "60px"}} /> */}
                            <img src={VesselExportIMG} alt="Excel Export" style={{height: "120px"}}/>
                        </Button>
                    </Col>
                    <Col xs={6} lg={6}>
                        <div style={{display: "flex",width: "100%",height: "100%",flexDirection: "column",justifyContent: "center"}}>
                            <div style={{marginTop: "5px",width: "100%",height: "50%",color: config.KSTColors.MAIN,fontSize: "32px",
                                display: "flex",justifyContent: "center",alignItems: "center"}}>
                                Download Template
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Col>
            <Modal size="lg" show={exportModalOpen} onHide = {() => setExportModalOpen(false)} aria-labelledby="VRTemplateDownload" centered>
                <Modal.Header style={{ backgroundColor: '#e6e6e6' }}>
                    <Modal.Title id="VRTemplateDownload">Export Vessel Report Template</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <span style={{fontSize: "12px"}}>Are you sure to generate {loggedInVesselName} vessel report?</span>
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer style={{ color: '#04588e' }}>
                    <Button onClick={() => setExportModalOpen(false)} style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', color: '#04588e', paddingTop: '2px', paddingBottom: '2px', paddingLeft: '20px', paddingRight: '20px' }}>Cancel</Button>
                    <ExcelFile filename={`${loggedInVesselName}_DailyLogTemplate`} element={<Tooltip title="Export Daily Log Template" placement="bottom"><Button style={{ backgroundColor: '#04588e', color: 'white', paddingTop: '2px', paddingBottom: '2px', paddingLeft: '20px', paddingRight: '20px' }}>Daily Log</Button></Tooltip>}>
                        <ExcelSheet dataSet={generatedData} name="Daily Log" />
                    </ExcelFile>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </Container>
    );
};

export default withMessageManager(VesselReportExcelGenerator);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should look into more programming approaches like the one in pandas library on python.