# Reading two Tables from a Excel Worksheet

Tags: python, excel, pyspark

[image]I have a Excel sheet which consists of two tables.I want to read them as two separate data frames.Is it possible?

Comment: please provide more details on how the tables look like in your exacel sheet

Comment: I have added a screenshot;) @Sadra

Comment: look at here < https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367805/pandas-read-excel-multiple-tables-on-the-same-sheet>